How to export the type of a computed property in Vue3?
I have a Vue3 component that makes some GraphQL requests. It gets back a big block of JSON and I have a computed to get the value I need from it. I want to pass this value to a child component as a prop.
However, in the child component, I need to be able to type my defineProps call. Since I want to accept the computed value, I need to have that type here to show it. The computed property I have is very large, so I don't want to manually type this outside of my component and import it into both. Instead of manually typing it, I just use the typeof operator.
How do I export this type?
// Parent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const { results } = useQuery(...)
const myComputed = computed(() => results.nested.item.is.here)
</script>

<template>
  <Child :passToMe="myComputed" />
</template>


// Child.vue
const props = defineProps<
  passToMe: ???
>()

I saw that you can export from a component with a separate <script> tag, which would work BUT it isn't scoped to see the computed property from my <script setup>.
I could just use the type of the gql results, but since this value is nested, that doesn't quite work.
I can't move the query down to the Child level just to get the type there, because I need other components to use the <Child> component and this type in the <Parent> computed is the minimumally required type I want to enforce.
So how do I export this type to use in multiple places?

A computed is unwrapped, passToMe's type is whatever type "results.nested.item.is.here" is.

@EstusFlask absolutely, but how do I export the type from the parent to the child. The type is a huge object with many fields, I don't want to manually type it out. It would take me hours when I should be able to do something akin to:export typeof myComputed.value and import it in the child.

Generally you need to manually type it. It's already an additional job and potential point of failure for defineProps to handle imported types, I believe this was unavailable at some point. Whether it's easy to avoid this depends on the specifics of useQuery. What is this, @vue/apollo-composable?  Probably you could extract the type from it. A straightforward approach would be to move useMyQuery = () => useQuery(...) to a separate module and use ReturnType. Since this is something that's reused between components,  it belongs to a separate module any way

Vue SFCs aren't generally supposed to export anything but a component itself. They can do named exports but that this fails in some IDEs and other tools proves this is an edge case

It just seems like a big oversight if you can't export types used in a component when you have to use said type in a child/parent component.
"since its reused, it belongs to a separate module anyway". That makes sense to me, but having to manually type it out by hand when it already exists somewhere in code seems like an oversight.

The problem in your case is that useQuery() is in the scope of setup function, while an export is supposed to be at top-level, it's not just a problem with 
you can get the type of "results.nested.item.is.here" with typeof
const results = {
  nested: { 
    item: {
      is: {
        here: "hello"
      }
    }
  }
}
export type propsType = typeof results.nested.item.is // { here: string }

Then import the type propsType in your Child component.
typeof is a bit special because it does not the same thing in javascript runtime and in typescript type declarations.
The following line will give you the javascript type: either "string", "object", "number" ... It's not what you need here.
export const runTimeType = typeof results.nested.item.is // "object"

Alternatively if you have access to the type of results you can do something like that:
interface IResult {
  nested : {
    item : {
      is : {
        here: string
      }
    }
  }
}

const results: IResult = {
  nested: { 
    item: {
      is: {
        here: "hello"
      }
    }
  }
}

export type propsType = IResult["nested"]["item"]["is"] // { here: string }

Generally, I would be cautious with the use of typeof because if typeof useQuery(...) changes, it would also change props type of Child implicitly, potentially introducing bugs if the new type is not compatible with how Child uses the data.

Thanks, this is good enough. I didn't realize you could get a nested type. As the useQuery types are external to the computed, and the computed just gets the nested type, we can do that in a separate module and import it both places. Thank you
